# Developing Augmented Reality Apps for Android Studio 2022

Tags: android, android-studio, unity-game-engine, opengl-es, augmented-reality

I want to create an Android App which supports Augmted reality but it seems that the technologies are getting worse.

Since Google stopped working on Sceneform there are only 2 options left: Using ARCore with OpenGL which is basically impossible because there are hardly any docs out there.
Or using AR Foundation but that is also not working properly and takes a lot of time to build because of the long building time.

Most of tutorials are about Google Sceneform and I just have the feeling that Sceneform did a great job and I don't understand why Google closed this project.
I'm familiar with frameworks like Vuforia but I would need a reliable plane detection tool which Vuforia does not provide as far as i know.

Does anybody have suggestions what I can use instead? Does anybody has experience with AR?

Comment: As Sceneform is open-source there are continuation projects like: https://github.com/SceneView/sceneform-android

Comment: "*I don't understand why Google closed this project*" They're Google. They don't have to have reasons to stop or start projects; they merely do.